# Camera2 API preview with wrong proportions and how to take a square picture

Tags: android

Based on this article [android-camera2-api-example-tutorial](https://inducesmile.com/android/android-camera2-api-example-tutorial/)

I created a camera2 activity for my application, by changing some code to obtain a final squared image.
While the result is nearly perfect eg. on a Galaxy S7, it is a little streched on other phones and on various emulators too.

Here my .xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/camera_constraint"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="rapture.engineering.wareapp.MainActivity">

    <TextureView
        android:id="@+id/camera_textureview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="284dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/camera_background"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/camera_background"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/camera_textureview"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/camera_snap"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="h,1:1"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline9"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/camera_background"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/snap"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline10" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/guideline9"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.3" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/guideline10"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.7" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And here the partially modified code:

```
package rapture.engineering.wareapp;
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.ImageFormat;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.graphics.SurfaceTexture;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraCaptureSession;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraCharacteristics;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraDevice;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraMetadata;
import android.hardware.camera2.CaptureRequest;
import android.hardware.camera2.TotalCaptureResult;
import android.hardware.camera2.params.StreamConfigurationMap;
import android.media.Image;
import android.media.ImageReader;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.HandlerThread;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.Size;
import android.util.SparseIntArray;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.Surface;
import android.view.TextureView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by stefa on 29/04/2017.
 */

public class Camera extends AppCompatActivity{
    Bitmap bitmapImage;

    ImageView cameraBackground;

    private static final String TAG = "AndroidCameraApi";
    private ImageButton takePictureButton;
    private TextureView textureView;
    private static final SparseIntArray ORIENTATIONS = new SparseIntArray();
    static {
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_0, 90);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_90, 0);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_180, 270);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_270, 180);
    }
    private String cameraId;
    protected CameraDevice cameraDevice;
    protected CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSessions;
    protected CaptureRequest captureRequest;
    protected CaptureRequest.Builder captureRequestBuilder;
    private Size imageDimension;
    private ImageReader imageReader;
    //private File file;
    private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION = 200;
    private boolean mFlashSupported;
    private Handler mBackgroundHandler;
    private HandlerThread mBackgroundThread;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.camera);
        init();
        //runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            //@Override
            //public void run() {
                DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
                getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
                ConstraintLayout layout = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_constraint);
                cameraBackground = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.camera_background);
                ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams params = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) cameraBackground.getLayoutParams();
                params.topMargin = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
                cameraBackground.setLayoutParams(params);
            //}
        //});
        assert textureView != null;
        textureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(textureListener);
        assert takePictureButton != null;
        takePictureButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                takePicture();
            }
        });
    }
    TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener textureListener = new TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
            //open your camera here
            openCamera();
        }
        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
            // Transform you image captured size according to the surface width and height
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surface) {
            return false;
        }
        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surface) {
        }
    };
    private final CameraDevice.StateCallback stateCallback = new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onOpened(CameraDevice camera) {
            //This is called when the camera is open
            Log.e(TAG, "onOpened");
            cameraDevice = camera;
            createCameraPreview();
        }
        @Override
        public void onDisconnected(CameraDevice camera) {
            cameraDevice.close();
        }
        @Override
        public void onError(CameraDevice camera, int error) {
            cameraDevice.close();
            cameraDevice = null;
        }
    };
    final CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback captureCallbackListener = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onCaptureCompleted(CameraCaptureSession session, CaptureRequest request, TotalCaptureResult result) {
            super.onCaptureCompleted(session, request, result);
            //Toast.makeText(Camera.this, "Saved:" + file, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            createCameraPreview();
            Variables.CameraResult = 1;
            bitmapImage = null;
            //createCameraPreview();
            finish();
        }
    };
    protected void startBackgroundThread() {
        mBackgroundThread = new HandlerThread("Camera Background");
        mBackgroundThread.start();
        mBackgroundHandler = new Handler(mBackgroundThread.getLooper());
    }
    protected void stopBackgroundThread() {
        mBackgroundThread.quitSafely();
        try {
            mBackgroundThread.join();
            mBackgroundThread = null;
            mBackgroundHandler = null;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    protected void takePicture() {
        if(null == cameraDevice) {
            Log.e(TAG, "cameraDevice is null");
            return;
        }
        CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        try {
            CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraDevice.getId());
            Size[] jpegSizes = null;
            if (characteristics != null) {
                jpegSizes = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP).getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.JPEG);
            }
            int width = 300;
            int height = 300;
            int forcedheight = 300;
            if (jpegSizes != null && 0 < jpegSizes.length) {
                width = jpegSizes[0].getWidth();
                height = jpegSizes[0].getHeight();
                forcedheight = width;
            }
            //ImageReader reader = ImageReader.newInstance(width, height, ImageFormat.JPEG, 1);
            ImageReader reader = ImageReader.newInstance(width, forcedheight, ImageFormat.JPEG, 1);
            List<Surface> outputSurfaces = new ArrayList<Surface>(2);
            outputSurfaces.add(reader.getSurface());
            outputSurfaces.add(new Surface(textureView.getSurfaceTexture()));
            final CaptureRequest.Builder captureBuilder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE);
            captureBuilder.addTarget(reader.getSurface());
            captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);
            // Orientation
            int rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
            //captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION, ORIENTATIONS.get(rotation));
            captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION, ORIENTATIONS.get(rotation));
            //final File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/pic.jpg");
            ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener readerListener = new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {
                @Override
                public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
                    Image image = null;
                    try {
                        image = reader.acquireLatestImage();
                        ByteBuffer buffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
                        byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.capacity()];
                        buffer.get(bytes);
                        bitmapImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length, null);
                        if (bitmapImage.getWidth() > bitmapImage.getHeight()) {
                            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                            matrix.postRotate(90);
                            //bitmapImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapImage , 0, 0, bitmapImage.getWidth(), bitmapImage.getHeight(), matrix, true);
                            bitmapImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapImage , 0, 0, bitmapImage.getHeight(), bitmapImage.getHeight(), matrix, true);
                        }
                        else{
                            bitmapImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapImage , 0, 0, bitmapImage.getWidth(), bitmapImage.getWidth());
                        }
                        Variables.bitmap = bitmapImage;
                        //bitmapImage.recycle();
                        //runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        //    @Override
                        //    public void run() {
                                //variables.Snap = bitmapImage;
                                //bitmapImage.recycle();
                                //snap.setImageBitmap(bitmapImage);
                                //finish();
                        //    }
                        //});
                        //save(bytes);
                    } finally {
                        if (image != null) {
                            image.close();
                        }
                    }
                }

                //private void save(byte[] bytes) throws IOException {
                //    OutputStream output = null;
                //    try {
                //        output = new FileOutputStream(file);
                //        output.write(bytes);
                //    } finally {
                //        if (null != output) {
                //            output.close();
                //        }
                //    }
                //}
            };
            reader.setOnImageAvailableListener(readerListener, mBackgroundHandler);
            final CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback captureListener = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCaptureCompleted(CameraCaptureSession session, CaptureRequest request, TotalCaptureResult result) {
                    super.onCaptureCompleted(session, request, result);
                    //Toast.makeText(Camera.this, "Saved:" + file, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    createCameraPreview();
                    Variables.CameraResult = 1;
                    bitmapImage = null;
                    finish();
                }
            };
            cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(outputSurfaces, new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onConfigured(CameraCaptureSession session) {
                    try {
                        session.capture(captureBuilder.build(), captureListener, mBackgroundHandler);
                    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onConfigureFailed(CameraCaptureSession session) {
                }
            }, mBackgroundHandler);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    protected void createCameraPreview() {
        try {
            SurfaceTexture texture = textureView.getSurfaceTexture();
            assert texture != null;
            texture.setDefaultBufferSize(imageDimension.getWidth(), imageDimension.getHeight());
            //texture.setDefaultBufferSize(imageDimension.getWidth(), imageDimension.getWidth());
            Surface surface = new Surface(texture);
            captureRequestBuilder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
            captureRequestBuilder.addTarget(surface);
            cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(surface), new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback(){
                @Override
                public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                    //The camera is already closed
                    if (null == cameraDevice) {
                        return;
                    }
                    // When the session is ready, we start displaying the preview.
                    cameraCaptureSessions = cameraCaptureSession;
                    try{
                        updatePreview();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e){

                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                    Toast.makeText(Camera.this, "Configuration change", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }, null);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    private void openCamera() {
        CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        Log.e(TAG, "is camera open");
        try {
            cameraId = manager.getCameraIdList()[0];
            CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);
            StreamConfigurationMap map = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
            assert map != null;
            imageDimension = map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class)[0];
            // AddActivity permission for camera and let user grant the permission
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Camera.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION);
                return;
            }
            manager.openCamera(cameraId, stateCallback, null);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.e(TAG, "openCamera X");
    }
    protected void updatePreview() {
        if(null == cameraDevice) {
            Log.e(TAG, "updatePreview error, return");
        }
        captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);
        try {
            cameraCaptureSessions.setRepeatingRequest(captureRequestBuilder.build(), null, mBackgroundHandler);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    private void closeCamera() {
        if (null != cameraDevice) {
            cameraDevice.close();
            cameraDevice = null;
        }
        if (null != imageReader) {
            imageReader.close();
            imageReader = null;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION) {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                // close the app
                Toast.makeText(Camera.this, "Sorry!!!, you can't use this app without granting Camera permissions!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
            }
        }
    }

    private void init(){
        //snap = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        textureView = (TextureView) findViewById(R.id.camera_textureview);
        takePictureButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.camera_snap);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.e(TAG, "onResume");
        startBackgroundThread();
        if (textureView.isAvailable()) {
            openCamera();
        } else {
            textureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(textureListener);
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        Log.e(TAG, "onPause");
        //closeCamera();
        stopBackgroundThread();
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy(){
        //stopBackgroundThread();
        closeCamera();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

What I edited from the source code:

I removed the SAVE to File function (the image is stored in memory and used later)

I used this to get a square preview, by hiding part of the screen:

```
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
        ConstraintLayout layout = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_constraint);
        cameraBackground = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.camera_background);
        ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams params = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) cameraBackground.getLayoutParams();
        params.topMargin = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
        cameraBackground.setLayoutParams(params);
```

I modified this code to try to read a square part of the image:

```
    int width = 300;
    int height = 300;
    int forcedheight = 300;
    if (jpegSizes != null && 0 < jpegSizes.length) {
        width = jpegSizes[0].getWidth();
        height = jpegSizes[0].getHeight();
        forcedheight = width;
    }
    //ImageReader reader = ImageReader.newInstance(width, height, ImageFormat.JPEG, 1);
    ImageReader reader = ImageReader.newInstance(width, forcedheight, ImageFormat.JPEG, 1);
```

And I modified this to crop the result:

```
                bitmapImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length, null);
                if (bitmapImage.getWidth() > bitmapImage.getHeight()) {
                    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                    matrix.postRotate(90);
                    //bitmapImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapImage , 0, 0, bitmapImage.getWidth(), bitmapImage.getHeight(), matrix, true);
                    bitmapImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapImage , 0, 0, bitmapImage.getHeight(), bitmapImage.getHeight(), matrix, true);
                }
                else{
                    bitmapImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapImage , 0, 0, bitmapImage.getWidth(), bitmapImage.getWidth());
                }
                Variables.bitmap = bitmapImage;
```

Finally I found a similar question here: [the-ideal-surfaceview-camera-orientations-and-proportions-avoiding-preview-stretching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40974598/the-ideal-surfaceview-camera-orientations-and-proportions-avoiding-preview-stre)

But I really prefer to try to make my code working... if possible... Thanks a lot

Comment: Have you checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34638651/how-to-get-an-android-camera2-with-11-ratio-like-instagram

Comment: Preview: [link](http://www.rapture.engineering/preview.jpg)

Result: [link](http://www.rapture.engineering/result.jpg)

The result is ok, the preview is streched...

Comment: Accepted answer fixes that issue, try implementing that also.

Comment: @AnithaManikandan sure i will try, thanks a lot

Comment: @AnithaManikandan downloaded the Camera2Basic, modified as the accepted answer says. It is working great, unfortunately the Take Photo Button does not save the picture in the Gallery, but this is another story. Very very thanks Anitha!

Comment: You are welcome @Rapture Engineering

Comment: Please note: The photo is not taken in emulator only. In a real phone the Camera2Basic works great!